# iOS: Internalization the Japanese date format to show Heisei Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization, calendar

I am developing an iOS application to support English and Japanese language.

I want to show date's Japanese Calendar type(Heisei).

Instead of showing English year 2013, i want to show Heisei year 25.

January 5, 25 Heisei (Region format: U.S., Calendar: Japanese, Language: English) 
平成25年1月5日 (Region format: Japan, Calendar: Japanese, Language: English)

NOTE: Even i am unable to see Heisei in iOS calendar when i change calendar type to Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

Use date formatters and locales. If you want "January 5, 25 Heisei" format, that's a locale identifier of `en_US@calendar=japanese`. The identifier for "平成25年1月5日" is `ja_JP@calendar=japanese`.

This code illustrates the use of both as I convert the "January 5, 25 Heisei" string to a `NSDate`, and then convert that `NSDate` back to a string in the form of "平成25年1月5日".

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US@calendar=japanese"];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"January 5, 25 Heisei"];

formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP@calendar=japanese"];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the calendar to be used is supposed to be at the convenience of the user, this is why, under Settings - General - International, there are different settings : Language, Region Format, and Calendar.
Therefore, what I believe is the best practice, would be to use the default NSLocale :

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
NSLog(@"Date : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

The following will output : `August 7, 25 Heisei` for a device set with an English Region format and a Japanese calendar, but `平成25年8月7日` for a device set with a Japanese Region format and a Japanese calendar.

If however you want to force the region format and calendar, you can create a specific locale for this, as Rob did in his answer.

Comment: i am able to get translated format '2013年8月7日' but not Heisei calendar.

Comment: Using the `[NSLocale currentLocale]` ? Did you set the calendar of your device to the Japanese one ?

Comment: Yes i have set currentLocale and changed setting to Japanese calendar,region japan and language japanese in device

Comment: And does it properly show the Heisei calendar in the settings when set like [this](http://i.imgur.com/TRhSNKr.png) ? If so, I have no idea sorry.